# VS 2019 to SQL 2019 deployment issue - SELECT permission was denied on the object 'server_principals'

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2019

Good day,

We are currently facing an issue with SSIS deployment from Visual Studio 2019 to SQL Server 2019. Using the Visual Studio "Integration Services Deployment Wizard" to deploy even a blank project, results in the following error: The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'server_principals', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 229)

Screenshot: [image: Error]

I use my AD account (Windows Authentication) to deploy from VS 2019. My AD account has db_owner access across the server and databases. We have also attempted to deploy the dtsx file from SSMS 2019 itself which also results in the same error

I am struggling to find any online resources which specifically make reference to the SELECT issue on "Server_principals"

Has anyone perhaps experienced something like this or can anyone please advise where the issue could lie or where to troubleshoot next?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mustaccio, reading through that did give me an idea of where to look for the solution. Adding the SELECT permission for sys.server_principals on database master for database role "Public", seems to have resolved the issue